# Requesting an active user page

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, users, recent-activity

In my opinion, providing us with an active user page that shows the list of recent active users is useful as we can monitor the active users without visiting each user profile. 
The list can be arranged in a grid of `m` rows by `n` columns and accompanied by labels representing the their reputations (and other info that you think they are important) and activities  such as "seen 2 minutes ago".

The following figure illustrates my idea. I am sorry. There is a typo in the following figure, `Active` must be changed to `active` to make it parallel to the other existing labels.

[image]

I think it is not too difficult to implement this. By adding a new action method and editing the view, done! 
Of course it is not urgently requested feature. If it is useful, it can be put in the development to-do list so it can be implemented together with other useful requests at once.

Any responses are welcome! Regardless of how difficult it is, could you explain whether or not there are negative effects of this request? Down voting without informative comments looks barbaric. :-)

### Edit:

If it is about user privacy, why is there a "seen 2 minutes ago" in the user profile page? I don't think there is a difference if we implement this feature.

Comment: How about "no".

Comment: And why precisely would you want to "monitor the active users"? Regardless of how difficult it is to implement, it would require *some* effort, and unless you can justify that effort, there are probably better things for the devs to do.

Comment: That tear-streaked gravatar is *creepy*.

Comment: I think people are downvoting because the example avatars creep them out.

Comment: I don't see a good reason to do this, either - what purpose would it serve? Stack Overflow is generally averse to any notion of a "social network" because that's not what it wants to be.

Comment: Albert! Where have you gone?

Comment: Honestly, I need this feature to monitor how active our moderators and my favorite members are rather than visiting their user profile one by one; it is very tedious in the digital era.

Comment: @doubleDown: I don't think so. Instead, I think lazy moderators will hate this idea. :-)

Comment: Honestly it doesn't occur to me why someone would need to monitor how active the mods or some users are. Plus, your browser has bookmarks for that purpose.

Comment: @Pekka웃: Adding this feature is far from making it to be regarded as a social network. :-)

Comment: @slhck: How can bookmarks do this job with one-click that produces the illustrated output above?

Comment: A large part of a moderators job is handling flags, and that is not publicly visible. So you won't be able to see a sigificant part of a moderato's activity anyway.

Comment: @all: I have not seen any negative effects for this feature request regardless of how difficult it is to implement. See you later...

Comment: Well **I** don't see any benefits to this. So it would be a waste of time at best, and creeper-stalker bait at worst.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: Do you see any benefit to "seen x minutes ago" in the user profile? Should it be removed to prevent stalkers from monitoring you?:-)

Comment: @hims056: Sorry I forgot I have posted the same thing 11 months ago. :-)

Comment: Three are over 1.8 million users on Stack Overflow. What makes you think the handful of people you're interested in will be in the first *X* pages of results, even when they *are* active? It seems your goal would be better served by simply bookmarking the pages of the people and checking them directly on demand.

Comment: @RobKennedy: Your comment really makes sense. You are genius. So it will be better if I request the "seen x minutes ago" label (below the tags in which they are active) added to the existing list of users.

Comment: Among other comments, Rob Kennedy's comment is the only one from which I can learn. Most of others (but not all for sure) are just waste of space. :-)

Answer (score 6):

One of the main things that I like about the SE network is that features like this are **not** included.  There is a nice degree of autonomy and privacy by not including this kind of feature commonly seen in online forums.

It is a good way to keep the focus on the questions and answers, not on the people which is the way it should be on a site like this.

Edited to add: "seen X minutes ago" does not necessarily mean that the person is active on that site at that moment.

Comment: Then why is there a "seen 2 minutes ago" in user profile? Your statements seems to be contradictory to the real fact. :-)

Comment: @o-O-o That's so you know if you should wait for him to reply to your comment or not. Also: it could be safely removed without much ado.

Comment: @Manishearth: It means no non-technical difference between my request and the existing "seen x minutes ago" in the user profile page.

Comment: @o-O-o: If there is no difference, than your requested feature doesn't add anything. Why would you ask for a feature when you think it doesn't add anything?

Comment: @sth: Do you understand the meaning of non-technical difference in my statement above? It refered to "That's so you know if you should wait for him to reply to your comment or not". The technical difference is we don't need to visit each user profile one by one. Period.

Comment: @o-O-o - just like my edit says - the "seen X minutes ago" does not necessarily mean that they are active, they may have quickly looked over part of the site and moved on to another that they may be a member of.