# What is the benefit to the "seen x minutes ago" on User Profile page?

Tags: discussion

I reword my sentence as follows. Mainly based on [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188681/requesting-an-active-user-page/188684?noredirect=1#comment581524_188681)

[image]

saying indirectly more and less that it is useful only for creepy stalkers. I totally disagree with that comment. And here I asked you:

> what is the benefit to the "seen x minutes ago" on User Profile page?

In other words, what led him to conclude that "seen x minutes ago" in grid layout (as my proposal) will be useful only for creepy stalkers but "seen x minutes ago" on the current user profile does not? It really does not make sense!

Comment: Sorry for my bad English. I am a bit difficult to express my idea in English.

Comment: Well, now that you have changed your question - I have deleted my response as it is now irrelevant to what you are asking.

Comment: even I am removing my answer....

Comment: @AnoopVaidya: Confirmed! Thanks.

Comment: Given your edit, BoltClock's comment is no longer out of context, however it just becomes a dupe of your previous question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're wondering where the famous and popular @UserABC has been lately, you might be interested to see that he/she/it was

> last seen 5 months ago

and therefore may have left the site, been hit by a bus, been eaten by Jon Skeet, etc.

It's just interesting.

It may also help you to decide whether some question poster is being lazy in their follow-ups, replies to comments, accepting an answer etc.. or whether they really have just not been on the site since.

Comment: Eaten by Jon Skeet??? Is that how he gets his reputation? absorbing it from those he eats??  Awesome!

Comment: Agree with you! It is useful not only for creepy stalkers. :-)

Answer (score 8):

> saying indirectly more and less that it is useful only for creepy stalkers. I totally disagree with that comment. And here I asked you:

Way to take things out of context. Boltclock was referring to [your proposal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188681), when he said "it"

He was *not* talking about the current "last seen" feature.

The last seen has some use. Many times, I leave a comment, and I determine if I want to wait for a reply by looking at the user's profile -- if the user is probably online, I may wait. Also, it tells you if the user has left the site/is taking a long SE break.

---

Stack Exchange is not a social network. Emphasis is on the posts, not the users.

IMO, this feature could be removed without much loss of functionality, but that's just my opinion on this.

---

Given your edit, BoltClock's comment is no longer out of context, however it just becomes a dupe of your previous question.

Comment: For me it is not out of context.

Comment: @o-O-o Umm, how? In BoltClock's comment "it" refers to your proposal. Here, "it" refers to the existing feature. There's a difference.

Comment: So what made him to conclude that "seen x minutes ago" in grid layout (as my proposal) will be useful only for creepy stalkers but "seen x minutes ago" on the current user profile does not? It does not make sense!

Comment: @o-O-o That's a completely different argument. My point here is that  regardless of usefulness, your proposal is _not_ the same as the existing one, and you cannot misquote people like that.

Comment: @o-O-o What led him to conclude that? Simple. The "last seen" has some marginal use in communication. The "currently online" doesn't -- SE is about posts, not users. If you need to contact the author of a particular post, good. If you just want any expert that's online, that's now what SE is for.

Comment: From beginning I always referred to the same thing which is the "seen x minutes ago" and it should not lead us to creepy stalkers. :-)

Comment: @o-O-o **yes**, but _BoltClock's comment_ refers to _your proposal_, not "seen x minutes ago". Quoting it here out of context is misleading.